# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND API Google Cloud

Tags: api, bots, getaddrinfo

I'm trying to execute API.AI tutorial for building a weather bot for Google Assistant (the one here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation)

I made everything successfully, created the bot within API, created the Fulfillments, installed NodeJS on my pc, connected Google Cloud Platform, etc.

Then I created the index.js file by copying it exactly how it's stated on API.ai tutorial with my API key from World Weather Organisation (see below).

But when I use the bot, it doesn't work. On the Google Cloud Platform the error is always the same:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.worldweatheronline.com
>   api.worldweatheronline.com:80
>
> ```
>     at errnoException (dns.js:28)
>     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup (dns.js:76)
> ```

No matter how often I do it I get the same error. So I don't actually reach the API. I tried to see if anything changed from WWO side (URL, etc.) but apparently no. I updated NodeJS and still same issue. I refreshed the Google Cloud platform completely and didn't help.

That one I really can't debug. Could anyone help?

Here's the code from API.ai:

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const host = 'api.worldweatheronline.com';
const wwoApiKey = '[YOUR_API_KEY]';
exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res) => {
  // Get the city and date from the request
  let city = req.body.result.parameters['geo-city']; // city is a required param
  // Get the date for the weather forecast (if present)
  let date = '';
  if (req.body.result.parameters['date']) {
    date = req.body.result.parameters['date'];
    console.log('Date: ' + date);
  }
  // Call the weather API
  callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
    // Return the results of the weather API to Dialogflow
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': output, 'displayText': output }));
  }).catch((error) => {
    // If there is an error let the user know
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': error, 'displayText': error }));
  });
};
function callWeatherApi (city, date) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create the path for the HTTP request to get the weather
    let path = '/premium/v1/weather.ashx?format=json&num_of_days=1' +
      '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(city) + '&key=' + wwoApiKey + '&date=' + date;
    console.log('API Request: ' + host + path);
    // Make the HTTP request to get the weather
    http.get({host: host, path: path}, (res) => {
      let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
      res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; }); // store each response chunk
      res.on('end', () => {
        // After all the data has been received parse the JSON for desired data
        let response = JSON.parse(body);
        let forecast = response['data']['weather'][0];
        let location = response['data']['request'][0];
        let conditions = response['data']['current_condition'][0];
        let currentConditions = conditions['weatherDesc'][0]['value'];
        // Create response
        let output = `Current conditions in the ${location['type']} 
        ${location['query']} are ${currentConditions} with a projected high of
        ${forecast['maxtempC']}°C or ${forecast['maxtempF']}°F and a low of 
        ${forecast['mintempC']}°C or ${forecast['mintempF']}°F on 
        ${forecast['date']}.`;
        // Resolve the promise with the output text
        console.log(output);
        resolve(output);
      });
      res.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Oh boy, in fact the reason was most stupid ever. I didn't enable "billing" on Google Cloud Platform and that's why it blocked everything (even though I'm using a free test of the API). They just wanted my credit card number. It works now

Comment: yup, just upgraded to blaze plan (which includes free tier data from spark)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying to hit my db. Billing wasn't the fix as I had billing enabled already.

For me it was `knexfile.js` setup for MySql - specifically the `connection` object. In that object, you should replace the `host` key with `socketPath`; and prepend `/cloudsql/` to the value. Here's an example:

```
connection: {
  // host: process.env.APP_DB_HOST, // The problem
  socketPath: `/cloudsql/${process.env.APP_DB_HOST}`, // The fix
  database: process.env.APP_DB_NAME,
  user: process.env.APP_DB_USR,
  password: process.env.APP_DB_PWD
}
```

Where `process.env.APP_DB_HOST` is your Instance connection name.

PS: I imagine that even if you're not using `Knex`, the `host` or `server` parameter of a typical DB connectionstring will have to be called `socketPath` when connecting to Google Cloud SQL.