# where is my HTTP request wrong?

Tags: node.js, http

Every time i submit the code below, i get this error. I'm new on Node.js and i'm trying to deploy a weather function with a simple api interaction (example in this page [link](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation)).

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.worldweatheronline.com 
api.worldweatheronline.com:80
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

```js
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
const host = 'api.worldweatheronline.com';
const wwoApiKey = 'here i write my api key';
exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res) => {
  // Get the city and date from the request
  let city = req.body.result.parameters['geo-city']; // city is a required param
  // Get the date for the weather forecast (if present)
  let date = '';
  if (req.body.result.parameters['date']) {
    date = req.body.result.parameters['date'];
    console.log('Date: ' + date);
  }
  // Call the weather API
  callWeatherApi(city, date).then((output) => {
    // Return the results of the weather API to Dialogflow
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': output, 'displayText': output }));
  }).catch((error) => {
    // If there is an error let the user know
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'speech': error, 'displayText': error }));
  });
};
function callWeatherApi (city, date) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Create the path for the HTTP request to get the weather
    let path = '/premium/v1/weather.ashx?format=json&num_of_days=1' +
      '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(city) + '&key=' + wwoApiKey + '&date=' + date;
    console.log('API Request: ' + host + path);
    // Make the HTTP request to get the weather
    http.get({host: host, path: path}, (res) => {
      let body = ''; // var to store the response chunks
      res.on('data', (d) => { body += d; }); // store each response chunk
      res.on('end', () => {
        // parsing and submit the response (not included in this code)
..
        // Resolve the promise with the output text
        console.log(output);
        resolve(output);
      });
      res.on('error', (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

How could i resolve it? Seems that my http request is wrong.

Comment: It sounds as if the DNS on the server is not resolving correctly. The domain api.worldweatheronline.com does exist.

Comment: Have you tried going on the machine and pinging api.worldweatheronline.com? `Pinging api.worldweatheronline.com [31.193.9.233] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 31.193.9.233: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=52
Reply from 31.193.9.233: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=52
Reply from 31.193.9.233: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=52

Ping statistics for 31.193.9.233:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 23ms, Maximum = 23ms, Average = 23ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this looks suspiciously like the issue reported here ([getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND API Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692267/getaddrinfo-enotfound-api-google-cloud)) which was a billing account set up; and I notice that you are using the premium API.

For that reason, and because the code is incomplete it is not possible to try debugging the code.

If the output of the console.() statements were included it might help.

The source of this kind of error is often the local networking environment. To rule this out I'd try:

1. Running working example, even using the free API from https://developer.worldweatheronline.com/api/code-examples.aspx, and/or
2. Trying your code example from a different machine on a different network.

Also, I'm not sure that the ping suggestion proves anything. Plenty of hosts won't respond to ping.