# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in node.js webhook for dialogflow

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I am trying to follow the dialogflow tutorial.  I have set up a node.js webhook, that is called from Dialogflow, inside the webhook code I call out to an api.  However, my node.js webhook is saying "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND".  This works fine when I run it in visual code but cannot find the api with in the nodejs webhook, when called via DialogFlow. There is something about the fact that it is being called from Dialogflow that seems to be making it not work.

I have spent a lot of time on this, and had previsouly discovered that DialogFlow wont work with https where it is a self signed certificate, as such I put an azure function, so the webhook calls the azure function and then the azure function call the api that I need. 
Sorry for the long post...

Here is the node.js code:

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

const apiUrl ="https://myapi";
exports.saledurationWebhook = (req, res) => {
  // Get the city and date from the request
 // let city = req.body.queryResult.parameters['geo-city']; // city is a required param
let city = "sdjk"; 
  // Call the weather API
  callSalesDurationApi(city).then((output) => {
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the weather API to Dialogflow
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);

    //res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': `I don't know the sales duration is but I hope it's quick!` });
    res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': err.message});

  })
  ;
};

function callSalesDurationApi(city) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log('API Request: ' + apiUrl);

    var myJSONObject = {
      "Inputs": "stuff"
    };

    request({
      url: apiUrl,
      method: "POST",
      json: true,   // <--Very important!!!
      body: myJSONObject
    }, function (error, response, body) {

      console.log("successfully called api");
      let output = "Current conditions in the " + body;

      console.log(output);
      console.log(body);
      resolve(output);

    });
  });
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Or what frther steps I can take to investigate it? I have already looked at the loges for the webhook, and for the azure function.

Any help would be really gratefully recieved, I have already wasted days on this. If this is a duplicate question then I am sorry, I have tried to look for existing answers on this issue.

Thanks Laura

Answer (score 1):

I have found this question already answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46692487/7654050

It is because I have not set billing up for this project. I thought it been set up as it is on my work account.